# The urls on Laravel working locally but not working on AWS EC2 linux centos 7

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos7

When I click on login button on my website, its go to `http://example.com/login?` which is expected but the page Not Found. But if i go to `http://example.com/index.php/login?` manually, then will go to the correct page "login page".

In my localhost its working properly when I click the login button.

- I had wrote this command on storage folder `chmod -R 777 storage`.

I am not sure if this is the case, do I need to write this command on another folders?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, its probably an apache or nginx mis-configuration.

Comment: thanks its fixed, I had to add some lines on`httpd.conf` to allow access for .htaccess file from apache server. I put the full answer down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed :)

- I had to go to `cd etc/httpd/conf`
- Next, edit `httpd.conf` by `sudo vim httpd.conf`, and add this at the end of the file:

  `<Directory "/var/www/html/your/laravel-project-folder/">
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>`

-Then restart the server `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`